# Passing values from View to Controller doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to send a variable from my view to a controller so I can use it in a different view. I've read a couple examples how to do this, however I can't get it working.

Here's my model:

```
public class GameResultsViewModel
{
    public int p { get; set; }
}
```

My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EndScreen(GameResultsViewModel results)
{
    return null;
}
```

Javascript function:

```
function submitResults() {
    var model = new Object();
    model.p = 3;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("EndScreen")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ results: model }),
        success: function() {
            alert("yay");           
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("nope");
        }
    });
}
```

I'm calling this function from a simple input:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitResults()" />
```

When I click the button it goes to the Action, but the variable is always 0. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: All you need is `data: { p: 3 },` and remove the `contentType:` option.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `results` from the posted data.

```
{ results: model }
```

MVC is binding to the model's property names. You can read more about [binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-beta-released#three) here.

```
function submitResults() {
    var model = { p: 3 };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("EndScreen")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function() {
            alert("yay");           
        }
    });
}
```

Had you changed your action to

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EndScreen(GameResultsViewModel results, string foo)
```

Then you would include `results`

```
var model = { p: 3 };

data: JSON.stringify({ results: model, foo: "bar" })
```

Comment: I changed it to your version, but p value in the controller is still 0. It seems to be a problem with JSON.stringify(model) line. Maybe it doesn't covert json to my viewmodel after it's sent. If I pass 2 variables like this:
data: {
    results: JSON.stringify(model),
    foo: "foo"
}
then the foo variable is sent fine, but results variable is not.

Comment: Append your latest attempt to your question.

Comment: try - data: JSON.stringify({ p : 3, foo: "bar" })

Comment: Can you change {"p": 3,foo:"bar"} like this.